# Creating a rectangle from center point with existing height and width size

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

Im trying to create a 10 x 10 rectangle from its center point. I found existing code that creates a rectangle by its center point, but the user has to give size by picking the opposite corner. I want to replace the manual part with known dimensions of 10 x 10. The user picks a point and a 10 x 10 rectangle is created off of that center point.

Here is the existing code that I found:

```
(defun C:CENRECT ( / pt1 ptc vec)

    (setq pt1 (getpoint "\nSpecify the center point: "))
    (setq ptc (getpoint pt1 "\nSpecify the corner point: "))
    (setq vec (mapcar '- ptc pt1))

    (entmake
        (list
            '(000 . "LWPOLYLINE")
            '(100 . "AcDbEntity")
            '(100 . "AcDbPolyline")
            '(090 . 4)
            '(070 . 1)
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (-(car vec))(+(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (+(car vec))(cadr vec)(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (+(car vec))(-(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (-(car vec))(-(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 210 (trans '(0.0 0.0 1.0) 1 0 T))
        )
    )

    (redraw)
    (princ)
)
```

Here I am trying to add the known dimensions of 10 x 10 instead of having the user pick the size manually.

```
(defun C:test ( / pt1 ptc vec len wid)
    (setq pt1 (getpoint "\nSpecify the center point: "))
    **(setq len 10)
    (setq wid 10)**
    (setq ptc (getpoint pt1 **len wid**))
    (setq vec (mapcar '- ptc pt1))

    (entmake
        (list
            '(000 . "LWPOLYLINE")
            '(100 . "AcDbEntity")
            '(100 . "AcDbPolyline")
            '(090 . 4)
            '(070 . 1)
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (-(car vec))(+(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (+(car vec))(cadr vec)(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (+(car vec))(-(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ pt1 (list (-(car vec))(-(cadr vec))(caddr vec))) 1 0))
            (cons 210 (trans '(0.0 0.0 1.0) 1 0 T))
        )
    )

    (redraw)
    (princ)
)
```

I get an error of too many arguments. Need to figure how to give the opposite corner of 10 x 10 instead of the user doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the fixed dimensions of the resulting rectangle ahead of time, the code can be reduced to the following:

```lisp
(defun c:cenrect ( / c z )
    (setq z (trans '(0 0 1) 1 0 t))
    (if (setq c (getpoint "\nSpecify center: "))
        (entmake
            (list
               '(000 . "LWPOLYLINE")
               '(100 . "AcDbEntity")
               '(100 . "AcDbPolyline")
               '(090 . 4)
               '(070 . 1)
                (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ c '(-5 -5)) 1 z))
                (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ c '( 5 -5)) 1 z))
                (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ c '( 5  5)) 1 z))
                (cons 010 (trans (mapcar '+ c '(-5  5)) 1 z))
                (cons 210 z)
            )
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

Here, the polyline vertices are calculated relative to the supplied center point (with respect to the active UCS), and such vertices are then transformed relative to the Object Coordinate System (OCS).

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq pt1 (getpoint "\nSpecify the center point: "))
(setq len 10)
(setq wid 10)
(setq vec (list len wid 0 ))

(entmake...... 
)
```

Should be OK.